# how to differ between message.content.startswith('$del') and message.content.startswith('$delall') while writing for a discord bot in py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

recently I was leaning to create discord bots. But came across this. How do I differ between

```
if message.content.startswith('$del'):
    if 'jokes' in db.keys():
      index = int(message.content.split('$del ', 1)[1])
      msg = delete_joke(index)
      if msg == "No jokes to delete":
        await message.channel.send(msg)
      else:
        await message.channel.send('deleted successfully')
    else:
      await message.channel.send('No jokes in the database')
```

and

```
 if message.content.startswith('$delall'):
    await message.channel.send(del_all())
```

Since message.startswith("") only checks for the starting characters, so it always calls '$del' even if I give '$dellall' as the command.

One way I figured was to write `if message.content.startswith('$del'):` at the end of all '$del' I might use, but it would still call '$del'. And won't it become a problem as the code and command increase? If there's any other better way, please let me know.

Comment: The `if` statements are not connected. Use `elif` to do that. Start with the `if message.content.startswith('$delall'):` block and after that `elif message.content.startswith('$del'):`.

Comment: That prevents calling both ifs. Thanks! But is there any other way? Because it still doesn't resolves the main issue of having to format all ifs in order to prevent calling '$del' instead of '$delall' in case of higher number of '$del' commands...

Comment: No, there isn't (at least not any really easy way). In the end "$delall" starts with "$del".

Answer (score 0):

You could split the message.content first like you did in your first if statement to get the index but this time you get the first item of the splited message:

```py
msg = message.content.split()
if msg[0] == "$del":
  #rest of the code
elif msg[0] == "$delall":
  #rest of the code
```